# How to change the active directory for the azure subscription trough REST api

Tags: azure, active-directory

I created one azure subscription manaully through azure portal called "susbcription1" . But where to tie active directory to subscription  while creation . Though I know we can do it later in settings--> select subscription--> edit directory.

1. Is there any REST api to create the azure subscription?
2. If no REST api to create subscription , then is there any REST api to tie the already created subscription with the desired active directory like how we can do in settings tab?

Answer (score 0):

No and no. Sorry.

I would love to hear from you what you're trying to achieve - there might be another solution. Let me know if you want to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

There're a couple of things you have to consider. First, what type of agreement and subscriptions you like to manage at rest.

For Enterprise Agreements you first need an account on the ea.azure.com.
Then you need a SPN and associate it with the role `SubscriptionCreator`, which has the Role definition Id of `a0bcee42-bf30-4d1b-926a-48d21664ef71`

This is how you Authorize Service-Principal for managing Subscriptions at REST on EA:

```
PUT  https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/{{billingAccountName}}/enrollmentAccounts/{{enrollmentAccountName}}/billingRoleAssignments/{{billingRoleAssignmentName}}?api-version=2019-10-01-preview
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{Token]]

{
  "properties": {
    "principalId": "{{PrincipalId}}",
    "principalTenantId": "{{TenantId }}",
    "roleDefinitionId": "/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/{{billingAccountName}}/enrollmentAccounts/{{EnrollmentAccount}}/billingRoleDefinitions/a0bcee42-bf30-4d1b-926a-48d21664ef71"
  }
}
```

Verify if the RoleAssigment:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/{{billingAccountName}}/enrollmentAccounts/{{enrollmentAccountName}}/billingRoleAssignments?api-version=2019-10-01-preview
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{RestAPIToken}}
```

This is how you create a subscription at REST on EA:

```
PUT  https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Subscription/aliases/MyFirstSubscription?api-version=2020-09-01
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{RestAPIToken}}

{
  "properties": {
    "billingScope": "/providers/Microsoft.Billing/BillingAccounts/{{billingAccountName}}/enrollmentAccounts/{{enrollmentAccountName}}",
    "DisplayName": "MyFirstSubscription",
    "Workload": "DevTest"
  }
}
```

Here is the official [Documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/assign-roles-azure-service-principals#assign-the-subscription-creator-role-to-the-spn)